# Where can I find the facebook connect api for iphone?

Tags: ios, facebook

as I have a problem with the new facebook sdk for ios (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208736/facebook-dialog-logout-and-access-token-facebook-ios-sdk/4208881#4208881) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215797/fbdidlogin-never-called-facebook-ios-sdk)) I would try with the old api, but on git there aren't no more. Where could I see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found nothing about older versions than this of facebook connect for iphone...
But, I've downloaded this SDK in October but I haven't update it yet!
If it can be useful, I can host it on a server to allow you to download it :)

Comment: I didn't understand... do you have a precedent version of this https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/wiki ?

Comment: I saw that facebook connect sdk is updated some weeks ago... I don't know which version I have but I've downloaded it in october... However this is the version I have: http://cl.ly/3PPI Feel free to download it! :)

Comment: I meant this https://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk now deprecated, however I'll try with your files. Thank you very much :)